# how to get authentication provider from sharepoint through web services?

Tags: python, web-services, sharepoint, authentication, provider

How to get authentication provider from share point through web services?..

I am log in to share point from python application. I need to find the selected authentication provider from the share point site. how to get that?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot retrieve provider instance and then do something like `Membership.ValidateUser(username, password)`.

You need to create a reference to [the **Authentication** Web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcauthentication.aspx), perform login operation (C# example below - you have to do something similar in Python):

```
string siteUrl = "http://example.com/sites/hr";
AuthenticationService.Authentication client = new AuthenticationService.Authentication();

client.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
client.Url = siteUrl + "_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx";

AuthenticationService.LoginResult loginResult = client.Login(username, password);
if (loginResult.ErrorCode == AuthenticationService.LoginErrorCode.NoError)
{
    string cookie = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri(siteUrl));
}
```

and use obtained cookie.

---

Read the [Reading a SharePoint list with PHP](http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-php/) post - it might give you some ideas regarding accessing SharePoint from a non-Microsoft environment.